# How to get back the previous greeter?

Tags: release-juno, pantheon, gnome

Is there a way to revert to the previous desktop where there logon field was on the left?  I much prefer it to the newer, centered logon.

Comment: No - well you could do [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package) but I'd advise against it - here is the motivation https://blog.elementary.io/say-hello-to-the-new-greeter/